# Failing to add customized header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to add a customized header as follows, but nothing changes in the file (I'm using overleaf):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{CE_images/}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EA}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}


\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\title{Episode 1}
\date{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome :) could you provide a full compilable code example showing what's going wrong?

Comment: edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the changes because your title page is by default defined as "plain", i.e. no fancy headers or page numbers to make it look cleaner.
If you go to the 2nd page you'll see your changes.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{CE_images/}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EA}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}


\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\title{Career Episode 1}
\date{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Foo}
\newpage
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

You can also define the title page to not be plain by adding `\thispagestyle{fancy}` right after `\maketitle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{CE_images/}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EA}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}


\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\title{Career Episode 1}
\date{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @E.Aly I'm glad! Please remember to mark an answer as accepted with the green check mark if it works for you :)